# Why first fraction isn't being pushed to the right through the \hspace that I have put in front of it?

Tags: spacing

I wrote the following code to create the following below:

```
$\hspace{.25 in}\frac{24}{60}\hspace{.25 in}*\hspace{.06 in}\frac{36}{59}\hspace{.05 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{35}{58}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{34}{57}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{33}{56}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{32}{55}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{31}{54}$
```

[image]

However, notice how the first fraction is not being pushed to the right through the \hspace that I have put in front of it. Why is this the case, and how do I fix this so that the first fraction aligns with all the other ones?

Comment: please, give a fully compilable code

Comment: Of course it is pushed to the right, try `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a$\hspace{.25 in}\frac{24}{60}\hspace{.25 in}*\hspace{.06 in}\frac{36}{59}\hspace{.05 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{35}{58}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{34}{57}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{33}{56}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{32}{55}\hspace{.04 in}*\hspace{.04 in}\frac{31}{54}$
\end{document}`. I put an `a` in front to show that it works. (Of course, you use very different distances.)

Comment: please always give complete test files that show the problem, and also please edit the title to refer to the problem for future searches. a title "please help" could be on every question

Comment: Why don't you simply use  \cdot$ instead of  of the computer science notation `*` and hand-made spacing?

Comment: What's the reason for all those `\hspace` commands?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you define a macro for you binary operator and make any additional tweaks (if desired) to the spacing in that macro:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\Ast}{*}

\newcommand*{\MyExpression}{%
             \frac{24}{60}
        \Ast \frac{36}{59}
        \Ast \frac{35}{58}
        \Ast \frac{34}{57}
        \Ast \frac{33}{56}
        \Ast \frac{32}{55}
        \Ast \frac{31}{54}
}%

\begin{document}

$\MyExpression$

\renewcommand*{\Ast}{\,*\,}

\medskip\par
$\MyExpression$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `*` is already a binary operation symbol.

Comment: @egreg: Wow!! I still have a _lot_ to learn!! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"03} % \ast` By the way, `\ast` is an alias. It's the same in plain TeX.

Answer (score 3):

First, guessing an answer to your literal question: The very first space is missing because either (a) you didn't see it was actually there, having nothing before the formula to show the spacing or (b) this occurs in a paragraph right after a line break, and white space is "discarded" after a line break in a paragraph (so the margins line up). These are guesses without proper context. If it is being discarded this way, `\hspace*` will prevent that.

Second, and *not* an answer for irregular spacing: You can control the spacing for all the binary operators (+ - * \times and others) by setting \medmuskip, always using units of "mu" (math unit = 1/18 em) like

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{9mu}
```

or with flexibility

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{8mu plus 5mu minus 4mu}
```